# Easiest software VPN solution in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, vpn, sonicwall

At a client's office, their SonicWALL device is out of commission temporarily, so I've set up a Linksys WRT54G router in its place until we can get a fix.

They need some kind of VPN solution, though, for access until the SonicWALL is back online.

What is the easiest way to get a VPN setup configured between Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP client machines?  I was thinking of something like [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/vpn.asp?lang=en) for the time being, but I'm not sure if doing it natively with Windows is easier...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RRAS's VPN is pretty easy to setup. Here is a [guide](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5805260.html).

Comment: I'm definitely trying that out later.  I'll post my results afterwards...

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Windows RRAS, its very easy to setup and manage, supports both PPTP and L2TP and RADIUS if you need it. The only significant downside is that if your running it, you can't run the windows firewall, but that's not always an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could flash the WRT54G with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) and run [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) in static keying mode.

Comment: I've read some other threads mentioning that.  I definitely want to use that setup for their DMZ wi-fi access point once this problem blows over and the SonicWALL is back.

Comment: The WRT's aren't terribly pokey. So you'd probably want to disable compression and make sure that you don't saturate it. But it works well.